# c++ for loop not working properly

Tags: c++, loops

This code works only when I uncomment

```
//else return "null";
```

on the 9th line, but that is not what I need. I tried replacing that line with

```
else continue;
```

but it won't work either. "currentCommand" is a c-style string.

```
std::string Parser::dest(){
//Determines whether C-command has a dest mnemonic
bool hasDest = false;
for (int i=0; i<strlen(currentCommand); i++){
    if (currentCommand[i] == '='){
        hasDest = true;
        break;
    }
    //else return "null";
}

if (hasDest == false) return "null";

std::string destm;
char temp;
int index = 0;
temp = currentCommand[index];
while (temp !=  '='){
    destm += temp;
    index++;
}   
return destm;
}
```

I was supposed to get an output when I call this function, and I get it when I uncomment `//else return "null"` .. but it is not the output I need.  But when I leave that line commented, I get no output, and after a while this error appears:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>
> what():  std::bad_alloc
>
> 1Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: You're returning "null" if *the first character* of `currentCommand` is not `'='`.  Probably not what you intended.  If it *is* what you intended then you certainly have an odd way of going about checking the first element in an array...

Comment: A) Why are you using a mix of c-style strings with std::string? B) What "doesn't work"? C) What is the expected behavior?

Comment: what you want to do with this loop

Comment: Just a suggestion to promote cleaner code: try using [`index()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/index) to locate the `=` char instead of writing your own.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I want to return "null" if there is no '=' character in the currentCommand array. Otherwise I want to return a copy of the string  currentCommand containing every character before the '=' char. So for example, if the array is "MD=D+A" I want to return "MD".

Comment: I didn't know about that null pointer. I corrected it, but still not working =(.

Comment: @LucasMezalira, How about using a `std::string` and just returning `str.substr(0, str.find('='));`? If you're returning everything up to the equals, I would expect the whole string back if not found, not "null" or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp = currentCommand[index];
while (temp !=  '='){
    destm += temp;
    index++;
}
```

Nothing changes "temp" in that while loop....not surprised you get a bad_alloc at some point.
Maybe

```
while ((temp = currentCommand[index++]) != '=') {
    destm += temp;
}
```

Comment: Again, I've spent a lot of time and patience in something so simply corrected -_- .....Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the first character is not "=" the 'else' statement immediately exits the function.
What you really intended is: 'if the entire for loop didn't find the '=' then execute the else statement. So the 'else' should be after the for loop. But instead you inserted it inside.
So now your code is saying: if the first character is not "=" just exit.

But don't worry, the line after the loop `if (hasDest==false)` will do exactly what you need so it is completely OK that you commented the else. It was erroneous anyway.

And another thing, You should return NULL as constant which is defined as (void*)0 and not a string saying the English word "null". Otherwise you might get error because you allocate a char array on the stack of the function and return a pointer to it, but this array is discarded when function terminates.

Comment: `NULL` is not definitively `(void*)0`. And wait, the problem you describe with returning `"null"` is non-existent. Returning a string literal will copy it into the `std::string` being returned. Returning `NULL` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

temp doesnt change in the while loop -> infinite loop -> every pass adds a new char to string -> memory exhaustion

Answer (score 0):

You are testing that your first character in the string is `'='` and of it's not you return `null`. Your next while loop does not do anything since the condition checks if the first character is different from `'='`. And at this point you already know it is not, otherwise you would have already returned `null`. So you get an uninitialized string that leads to the strange behavior you notice.

I assume you want to copy all characters after `'='`. Then you should start at `index=1` and test for end of string (or is ur sting finished by another `'='`)? Plus the loop is wrong. You should update the temp variable to `currentcommand[index]` inside the loop...currently you increase the index but `temp` remains the first character....

Answer (score 0):

In actual fact, your `for` loop is not the issue at all. (Although it might still be a good idea to use an existing function like `strchr`.)

This is the code that's causing the problem:

```c
std::string destm;
char temp;
int index = 0;
temp = currentCommand[index];
while (temp != '=') {
    destm += temp;
    index++;
}
```

You set `temp` to whatever the first character in the string is, but in your while loop, you never actually change the value of `temp`. Your `destm` will keep growing, adding on the initial value of `temp` over and over until you run out of memory (which explains why you're getting a `bad_alloc`).